# Get all elements at index in 2d array

Tags: groovy

I am writing an ML algorithm where I have a list of tuples like so:

```
[ [17582.0, 6.382129, 0.876581], [9868.0, 2.694977, 0.432818], [18333.0, 3.951256, 0.3333] ...]
```

So, all index=0 refer to a specific value for a feature. To normalize, I need to get the min and max of every feature.

Is there a short hand way to get all elements at index = 0 or index = 1, and so on of the tuples?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your values are in a variable `list`

Then you can simply do:

```
def firstElements = list*.head()
```

If you need a specific position, then you can also do:

```
def secondElements = list*.getAt(1)
```

To get a column-wise min and max, just transpose the list, then do the calculation:

```
def cwMinMax = list.transpose().collect { [it.min(), it.max()] }
```

Comment: What about index = 1? Can spread operator somehow be used for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Not sure what it means now ;-)

Comment: Haha.. from each of the inner lists, get ALL elements at index = 0,1,...n. How about now?

Comment: `*.get(2)` :P that was easy

Comment: If you want more than one from each, you can also do: `list*.getAt([1, 2])` to get the 2nd and 3rd element from each element

Comment: Oh I see. Basically, I am trying to get a column-wise min and max instead of row-wise. :)

Comment: Which would be the same as `list.*getAt( 0 ).min()`, performance-wise, right?

Comment: Yeah...but that just gets the minimum ;-P